# Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME Flashback - how to change desktop icon text color?

Tags: themes, 20.04, colors, gnome-flashback

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and want to use the GNOME Flashback session, as I'm used to the old GNOME look and don't like the new one. I also installed the Radiance theme because I like it more than default ones installed with Ubuntu. I even did some minor tweaks to theme's CSS files to get rid of a few things that annoyed me (e.g. the very ugly "overshoot" effect when scrolling past top or bottom of a window) and everything is working well.

However, there's one thing I don't know how to change. The default text color for desktop icon labels is too dark and is hardly visible on the default background:
[image: here is the screenshot]

I don't know how to change it. From what I could find on the Net, people advise to change the color for `.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item` CSS element. I found this element in `gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css` and `gtk-3.20/apps/nautilus.css` files and changed both, however it didn't work - the color didn't change.

Please tell me what should I change in the CSS files to change this color?

Comment: This will end with installing MATE DE at the end, I think. GNOME FlashBack degrading too fast. Desktop is controlled by [some extension](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback) nowadays with limited functionality.

Comment: I was (and currently still am) using Ubuntu MATE 18.04 for a while, because of my old computer being a 32 bit one, so I cannot install the main Ubuntu variant, which is now 64 bit only. However, I found out that some things in the DE were failing and I had to disable them - probably MATE DE is not tested as well as GNOME. On a new computer I just bought I would like to return to proper GNOME.
The color in question definitely CAN be changed, as default themes (eg. Yaru) are doing this. It's only a question how? Wish there was some detailed documentation on creating themes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gf-icon label { color: red; }` should change color to red.

Comment: BIG THANKS! It works!
However, I found out that "gf-icon" does never occur in the original theme .css files. But default Ubuntu themes somehow set this color to white, while any other themes don't. Even if i make an exact copy of original theme's files and give it another name, it doesn't set this color and it still remains at dark default as in my example.
I also found another issue related to exactly the same situation (default vs non-default themes), which I'm about to post soon. Could you please look at it as well?

Comment: `gnome-flashback` has custom css for some themes - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/tree/master/data/theme.

Comment: Thank you again! Could you please look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245851/ubuntu-20-04-gnome-flashback-snap-shop-transparent-on-non-default-themes ? Looks like a bit similar issue...