# Top Bar Theme 20.04

Tags: 20.04

*On Question "[Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME Flashback - how to change desktop
icon text color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245624/ubuntu-20-04-gnome-flashback-how-to-change-desktop-icon-text-color)"* there is a pictures of an desktop with light brown
Top Bar similar to Radiance theme.
I been trying to get exactly the same but failed.
Can some one let me know how to achieve this theme
Appreciate very much
Thank you

Comment: A link to the question may be helpful to us. You may also want to take a screenshot of your desktop and upload it in imgur.com and add a link to the screenshot [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1334631/edit).

Comment: Don't know if this is correct the Tirle in imgur is    Lumaja screenshot & Link

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1334631/edit) and add the link to the screenshot there.